# how to read Pictures Path To A File In A Different D: Drive?

Tags: php

local windows 2008 server iis with runing php. 
this web site path  `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxx`
this pictures path `D:\Fotograflar`
how to read pictures

this two code not running

```
<?php $file_dir = "D:/Fotograflar"; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $file_dir . '/' .$row[3];?>"></td>

<img src="<?php echo "file:///D:/Fotograflar/".$row[3];?>">
```

Comment: you can't mix file:// urls when doing http://. it's a major security risk and is forbidden by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change your picture location to inside the root, that way you can make image urls and show users images through IIS, without the large security risk.